# Are there any Profile Page theming scripts available? (e.g. Flavors.me)

Tags: php, jquery, themes

Recently there have been a number of sites which allow users to edit a profile page's background, font & colors. They use (presumably) custom made scripts which allow people to modify the designs based on a basic set layout template. Examples include:

- About.me
- Flavors.me

...where columns, headers and sidebars are already fixed based on a chosen layout.

Are there any resources which allow you to add such a functionality to a site and save the user's preferences?

I already have a way to retrieve a user's information & display it on a page using a ready-made design, but I'd prefer to add a small amount of flexibility. I currently use PHP (CodeIgniter) & jQuery, but I'd be interested to see how any kind of related project works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using jQuery already, you could probably put jQuery UI's [Themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) to good use.